# Pass object from javascript to Perl dancer framework

Tags: javascript, ajax, object, hash, dancer

I have following `ajax` code to pass values to `dancer framework`.

```
 BookSave: function(data) {
  ### data is an object that contain more than one key value pair
         var book = Book.code;
         $.ajax ({
              type: "GET",
              url : 'textbook/save/' + book + '/' + data,
              success: function(data) {
                  if(data.status == 1) {
                         alert("success");
                  } else {
                        alert("fail");
                  }
             },
          });
    },
```

In dancer:

```
any [ 'ajax', 'get' ] => '/save/:book/:data' => sub {
    set serializer => 'JSON';
    my $book = params->{book};
    my $data = params->{data};  ## This I am getting as object object instead of hash
};
```

Is there any way to pass object from js and getting as hash in dancer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, consider using the http PUT or POST verbs, and not GET.  Not only is doing so more semantically correct, it allows you to include more complex objects in the http body, such as your 'data' hash (serialized, per my comments below).

I've had limited success with Dancer's native AJAXy methods, plus there is a bug that causes problems in some versions of Firefox.  So instead, I serialize and then deserialize the JSON object.

Suggested changes (note I suggested changes to your routes as well):

```
$.ajax ({
    type: "PUT",
    url : '/textbook/' + book,
    data: {
        myhash : JSON.stringify(data)
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.status == 1) {
            alert("success")
        } else {
           alert("fail")
        }
    }
 })
```

and your Perl Dancer code changes as follows:

```
any [ 'ajax', 'put' ] => '/textbook/:book' => sub {
    set serializer => 'JSON';
    my $book = param('book');
    my $data = from_json(param('myhash'));
};
```

I did not go as far as testing this code, but it should at least give you a good starting point to finish solving this problem.

Good luck with your project!